# Centering a position:fixed div

Tags: css, position, fixed, centering

I have been trying for days to center a position:fixed element, a lot of solutions all around the web have been found and yet, either due to inefficiency or my own inexperience, none of them worked.

The scenario is as follows; I want to make an image visor, whenever you click a image a fixed div is made visible, holding said image, this is actually done via JavaScript.
The problem occurs when I want to center the div, no matter which resolution you are using.

```
#galleryimage{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:200;
    display:none;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#galleryimage img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

The images' width and height are unknown variables, I am not experienced enough with JS to handle it, so I wanted to do it with pure CSS. However, I never could get it centered.
Margin just won't work, and the formula with negative margin won't either, as I do not know the width and height variables of these images.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would use JavaScript + jQuery for this, to make life easier. Here's a good starting point for you:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style>
      #galleryimage{
        position:fixed;
        z-index:200;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
      }

      #galleryimage img{
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
      }

    </style>
    <body>

      <div id="galleryimage">

      <img src="" />

      </div>

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(){

        loadGalleryImage('your_image_name.jpg');

      });

      function loadGalleryImage(src){

        $("#galleryimage img").on('load', function(){

          $(this).css({marginTop: -($(this).height()/2), marginLeft: -($(this).width()/2)});
          $("#galleryimage").animate({opacity:1}, 200);
          $("#galleryimage img").off('load');

        });

        $("#galleryimage img").attr('src', src);

      }

      function hideGalleryImage(){
        $("#galleryimage").animate({opacity:0}, 200);
      }

    </script>
  </html>
```

This uses a few techniques. In CSS the image is absolutely positioned and placed at the 50% point for both top and bottom. Then, using jQuery, once we know the image is loaded, we can determine its width and height, and shove it left and up by half those values. That places it directly in the center of the screen. I added some animation stuff in there for prettiness :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:table-cell to vertically align something in the middle. You have to get the div to stretch to 100% of your fixed position div though. I have made a quick jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fm2GD/2/

Basically you have to have the image in a table cell:

```
#tableCell{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

which is in a "table" :

```
#table{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display:table;
}
```

which covers 100% of your fixed position div.